# How to create multiple rows from a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called result that has 11 columns and look like that

```
Name Seat FA1 FA2 Fa3 FB1 FB2 FB3 FC1 FC2 FC3
```

what I am trying to do is break each row into 3 rows so the rows can be like this

```
Name Seat FA1 FB1 FC1

Name Seat FA2 FB2 FC2

Name Seat FA3 FB3 FC3
```

Comment: what are the field names please?

Comment: Posting an answer doesn't seem to work but typically, you would use a `UNION ALL`. Alternatively, you could look into `PIVOT/UNPIVOT` but that might be overkill.

Comment: Oh - they are the field names - sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this technique - using a combination of cross apply and values to be extremely helpful - I got this from [here](http://sqlstudies.com/2013/04/01/unpivot-a-table-using-cross-apply/) where the author (Kenneth Fisher) argues it on performance grounds over use of unpivot. What I like most is the ease of layout control it provides and think it's easier than unpivot. It will work in SQL 2008.

```
SELECT
    Name
  , Seat
  , CA1.Aaisle
  , CA1.Baisle
  , CA1.Caisle
FROM UnPivotMe
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES 
                (FA1, FB1, FC1)
              , (FA2, FB2, FC2)
              , (FA3, FB3, Fc3)
            ) AS CA1 (Aaisle, Baisle, Caisle)
;
```

EDIT - sorry altered aliases to something more logical

Comment: +1 but you should rename to `aas, bees, cees` <g>

Comment: :) as long as it's understood - the naming chosen is up to the user

Answer (score 1):

If the types match, you could use...

```
SELECT Name, Seat, FA1, FB1, FC1 from result

UNION ALL

SELECT Name, Seat, FA2, FB2, FC2 from result

UNION ALL

SELECT Name, Seat, FA3, FB3, FC3 from result
```

This will depend on whether you want to filter out results, you may want to only show lines where you have values in all...

```
SELECT Name, Seat, FA1, FB1, FC1 
from result
WHERE (FA1 IS NOT NULL AND FB1 IS NOT NULL AND FC1 IS NOT NULL)
```